# WordPress shortcode plugin not working

Tags: plugins, shortcode, javascript

Shortcode not working for js error. page link
https://staging.sugrihini.com/test/ 
using

this `[circleaudio src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/piano.mp3"]`

Geeting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at main.js?ver=0.0.3:1
```

===================Plugin Code===========

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','circleaudioplayer_assets');
function circleaudioplayer_assets(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bar', plugins_url( '/progres-bar.css' , __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'player', plugins_url( '/player.js' , __FILE__ ),array("jquery"),'0.0.1',true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', plugins_url( '/main.js' , __FILE__ ),array("jquery","player"),'0.0.3',true);
    }

function circleaudioplayer( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'src' => ''
    ), $atts );

    return '<div class="mediPlayer">
    <audio class="listen" preload="none" data-size="250" src="' . $a['src'] . '"></audio></div></div>';

}

add_shortcode( 'circleaudio', 'circleaudioplayer' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid to declare that player is a dependency for your javascript file, the problem is that Jquery isn't recognized. Change this line:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main', plugins_url( '/main.js' , __FILE__ ),array("jquery","player"),'0.0.3',true);
```

into this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main', plugins_url( '/main.js' , __FILE__ ), ["jquery"] );
```

Also avoid to enqueue your script in the footer.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion. Now getting this Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at main.js:1     `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mediPlayer').mediaPlayer();
});`

Comment: Found a solution, the code should be `(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.mediPlayer').mediaPlayer();
    });
})(jQuery);`

Comment: @ShaifShahin yes,you need to use jquery in no conflict mode.